# Проблема с конструкторами "no matching function for call to..."

Tags: c++, классы

Пишу класс матриц и возникла проблема с конструкторами. В предпоследней строчке при вызове конструктора, принимающего на вход 3 переменные, компилятор выдает ошибку `no matching function for call to 'Matrix<3u, 1u, float>::Matrix(Vec3f)'`.

Вот код (я выкинул операторы, чтобы было проще найти ошибку):

```
#define temop2  template<size_t R1, size_t C1, size_t R2, size_t C2, class T>
#define temop1  template<size_t R, size_t C, class T>
#define vec_ini _Mat(vector<vector<T>> (R, vector<T> (C, 0.)))
#define x       _Mat[0][0]
#define y       _Mat[1][0]
#define z       _Mat[2][0]

template<size_t R, size_t C, class T> struct Matrix  
{
    Matrix (): vec_ini
    {}

    Matrix (T _x, T _y, T _z): vec_ini
    {
        _Mat[0][0] = _x;
        _Mat[1][0] = _y; 
        _Mat[2][0] = _z;
    }

    Matrix (T _x, T _y): vec_ini
    {
        _Mat[0][0] = _x;
        _Mat[1][0] = _y;
    }

    Matrix (Matrix<R, C, T>& v): vec_ini 
    { 
        *this = v; 
    }

    vector<T>& operator [] (const int i)
    {
        assert (i >= 0 && i < R);
        return _Mat[i];
    }

    Matrix<R, C, T>& operator = (Matrix<R, C, T> &m)
    {
        for(size_t i = R; i--; )
            for(size_t j = C; j--; )
                _Mat[i][j] = m[i][j];
        return *this;
    }

    vector<vector<T> > _Mat;
};

typedef Matrix<2, 1, float> Vec2f;
typedef Matrix<3, 1, float> Vec3f;
typedef Matrix<2, 1, int> Vec2i;
typedef Matrix<3, 1, int> Vec3i;

Vec3f m2v (Matrix<4, 1, float> m)
{
    return Vec3f (m[0][0]/m[3][0], m[1][0]/m[3][0], m[2][0]/m[3][0]);
}
```

Также, не знаю почему, ошибка пропадает, если убрать строку
`Matrix (Matrix<R, C, T>& v): vec_ini { *this = v; }`

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Ваш конструктор копирования требует на вход lvalue-ссылку на неконстантный объект (ака "неконстантная ссылка")

```
Matrix (Matrix<R, C, T>& v)
```

Вы же пытаетесь передавать туда временный объект

```
return Vec3f (m[0][0]/m[3][0], m[1][0]/m[3][0], m[2][0]/m[3][0]);
```

Неконстантная ссылка не может быть привязана к временному объекту. Поэтому вызвать вышеупомянутый конструктор копирования в данном контексте невозможно. Других подходящих конструкторов у вас нет. Возникает ошибка.

С чего это вдруг у вас параметр конструктора копирования (и оператора присваивания тоже) является неконстантной ссылкой? Почему вы убрали с ссылки константность?

---

Если убрать ваше корявое объявление конструктора копирования, то компилятор сгенерирует конструктор копирования для вашего класса самостоятельно. И у этого конструктора копирования параметр будет иметь *правильный* тип `const Matrix &`, т.е. этот конструктор копирования будет прекрасно вызваться в данном контексте. Поэтому ошибка и пропадает.

Тут возникает закономерный вопрос: учитывая, что ваш класс состоит просто из `vector<vector<T> > _Mat;`, зачем вы вообще писали конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания вручную? Чем вас не устроили неявные реализации, предоставляемые компилятором?

Comment: Простите, я тогда был в 8 классе :0 Ничего не понял, а сейчас понял, спасибо!